# using Realm in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, realm-mobile-platform

I am already using the Realm database in my iOS development and I am seriously considering moving to the Realm Object Server as my synchronization layer.

The problem is that I am also doing a browser based version of my product and I was wondering if Realm supports this or are planning to support it. I know you can use Firebase across both iOS, Android and HTML5 based apps but I only see that Realms supports the mobile platforms.

Anybody have any ideas how Realm Object Server fits into browser based apps?

Comment: given the lack of documented support, and the fact that the only JavaScript support for the Realm framework is React Native, I would highly doubt that there is a path to browser usage here.  Storing data like this would require File System access, especially for features like offline data access, and File System access is just not something browsers support now, or will support in the future.

Comment: however, the above comment *is just my opinion on the matter*;  the only reliable source of information regarding platform compatibility would be the platform developers, not their community support.

Comment: Yes I am just thinking that something like the in-memory realms they have on the native platforms coupled with the realm object server would be a really powerful combination